# Spring Security validate sessionId

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to make a service that takes a session id as parameter and check if this is a valid session or not.

Is there a way in spring security to check the given session id is valid or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you using authenticationManager, then in lifecycle can be injected 
`<bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl"/>`. SessionRegistry automaticly add session in registry. Then by injection

```
@Autowired
private SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
```

you can use SessionRegistry API to validate your principals.

Comment: Thnx but this is not what I need. The session id I have is not for the currently logged in user it is for another user. Consider I have two web applications one of them sends me a session id to check if this is a valid session id for an authenticated user or not. How can I access the currently active sessions from spring security?